# Intervals on which function is increasing and decreasing

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $p(x)=x^5-q^2x-q$ , where $q$ is a prime number. I want to understand how to determine when the function will be decreasing and increasing on the intervals given below.

We compute $p^{\prime}(x)=5x^4-q^2$ and look for the critical points.

$5x^4-q^2=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$

Hence we have to investigate the behavior of $p^{\prime}(x)$ for each of these intervals 
$(-\infty,-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}})$, $(-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}},\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}})$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}},\infty)$ this will indicate when the function will be increasing and decreasing. How can this be determined when the expression $\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$ contains a prime number???

The answer should be : the function will be increasing for $x<\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$ and strictly decreasing for $-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}<x<\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$ and strictly increasing again for $x>\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$

Can someone explain this last part? 
Thank you

Comment: You are asked to determine wether $p'(I_i)$ is less than or greater than zero for each one of the intervals you have determined, $I_i$.

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking for. How to determine whether the derivative will be positive or negative on these intervals?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the value of $q$?

Comment: nope, it just says, $q$ is a prime number

Comment: Oh, you're right. I see it now in the question. Well, we know that $x=0 \in I_2 \equiv (-\sqrt{q}/5^{1/4},\sqrt{q}/5^{1/4})$ and we have $p'(0) = -q^2 < 0$ and therefore $p(x)$ is decreasing on $I_2$.

Comment: Nicely done. Do you know how to proceed with the remaining two ones?

Comment: Hi, @user124471, my guess would be: since $p''(x) = 20 x^3$, we have that $p''(x < -\sqrt{q}/5^{1/4}) < 0 $ and $p''(x > \sqrt{q}/5^{1/4} )> 0$ and therefore, $p'(x)$ is monotonically increasing on $I_3$ and monotonically decreasing in $I_1$. Since we have proved that $p'(r_i)=0$, $p'(I_1)>0$ as well as $p'(I_2)$. Then, it follows the OP's answer for the character of $p(x)$.

Comment: this makes sense, thank you

Comment: These can be nicely shown in a more intuitive way by sketching $p'(x)$ and $p''(x)$. If you want me to post this as an answer, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have $q\gt 0$, the derivative is positive whenever $5x^4\gt q^2$, or equivalently $\sqrt 5 x^2\gt q$

This can happen two ways, either with $\sqrt[4]5x\gt \sqrt q$ if $x$ is positive, or $-\sqrt[4]5x\gt \sqrt q$ if $x$ is negative.

For a negative derivative, the inequalities are reversed.

I am not sure what you mean by "contains a prime number" - the function is presumably being taken over the real numbers, over which the [positive real] square and fourth roots of non-negative real numbers are well-defined.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.